# append object to array of objects in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

this is my schema in mongoose

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    vaccine: [{
        name: String,
        price: Number,
        availibility: Number,
        needed: Number
    }]

}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I have created a form which gives the input for vaccine object(name price availability and needed) and its data is available in req.body. How do I append this using mongoose?

Comment: notify me if you needed to update the specific object in array besides of insertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use findOneAndUpdate() :

```
let vaccine ={ ... } // you object trying to add
let filter = { ... } // your filter you are trying to target the collection

Company.findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $addToSet:  {vaccine: vaccine}})
```

if you want get your updated result just use  {new :true}.

full example:

```
let company = await Company.findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $addToSet:  {vaccine: vaccine}}, {new:true})
```